# react-table - How to implement useGlobalFilter for nested values in data?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-table, react-table-v7

I am providing `react-table` with some data that has nested values. Here in an example of an item in my data array:

```
"organization": "Lorem",
"orgId": "Ipsum",
"administrator": "Isaac Medina",
"location": {
  "address": "123 Main St",
  "suite": "Suite 403",
  "city": "City",
  "state": "ST",
  "zipcode": "60045"
},
```

I am able to use useGlobalFilter for non nested keys like `orgId` or `administrator`, but when I want to look for a location, `react-table` does not render any rows.

This is what I have on my onChange handler:

```
const onSearchInputChange = (e) => {
  setGlobalFilter(e.target.value);
};
```

I have tried looking into the documentation, but there isn't anything specific regarding this.

Thank you.